# Adding a new setting using Kirki or WP customizer with an if statement

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I have a radio box and an image setting in functions.php:

```
Spotlight_Kirki::add_field( 'spotlight_config', array(
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'settings'  => 'spotlight_layout_type',
    'label'     => esc_html__( 'Layout Type' , 'spotlight' ),
    'section'   => 'spotlight_general',
    'default'   => 'layout_dark',
    'priority'  => 0,
    'choices'   => array(
        'dark'      => esc_html__( 'Dark version', 'spotlight' ),
        'light'     => esc_html__( 'Light version', 'spotlight' ),
        'coloured'  => esc_html__( 'Coloured version', 'spotlight' ),
    ),
) );
if ( get_theme_mod( 'spotlight_layout_type', '' ) != 'coloured' ) {

    Spotlight_Kirki::add_field( 'spotlight_config', array(
        'type'      => 'image',
        'settings'  => 'spotlight_bg_image',
        'label'     => esc_html__( 'Background Image' , 'spotlight' ),
        'section'   => 'spotlight_general',
        'default'   => esc_html__( '', 'spotlight' ),
        'priority'  => 0
    ) );
}
```

So, as you can see, I tried to enable the `spotlight_bg_image` setting only if the previous radio box was set to anything but `coloured`. However, it doesn't get hidden when I choose one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_theme_mod` in that context will only work after you save and refresh. In order to hide a control based on the value of another control you can use the `active_callback` argument in the 2nd control like this:

```
Spotlight_Kirki::add_field( 'spotlight_config', array(
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'settings'  => 'spotlight_layout_type',
    'label'     => esc_html__( 'Layout Type' , 'spotlight' ),
    'section'   => 'spotlight_general',
    'default'   => 'layout_dark',
    'priority'  => 0,
    'choices'   => array(
        'dark'     => esc_html__( 'Dark version', 'spotlight' ),
        'light'    => esc_html__( 'Light version', 'spotlight' ),
        'coloured' => esc_html__( 'Coloured version', 'spotlight' ),
    ),
) );
Spotlight_Kirki::add_field( 'spotlight_config', array(
    'type'      => 'image',
    'settings'  => 'spotlight_bg_image',
    'label'     => esc_html__( 'Background Image' , 'spotlight' ),
    'section'   => 'spotlight_general',
    'default'   => esc_html__( '', 'spotlight' ),
    'priority'  => 0
    'active_callback' => array(
        array(
            'setting'  => 'spotlight_layout_type',
            'operator' => '!==',
            'value'    => 'coloured',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Documentation for that argument can be seen here: https://aristath.github.io/kirki/docs/arguments/active_callback.html

Normally in the WordPress Customizer `active_callback` will accept a callable function/method where you'd have to check the conditions you want, this is just a shortcut provided by Kirki to make things a little easier.

Comment: PS: Unfortunately, doesn't work inside a repeater.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that this won't work in repeaters. Think of the repeater field as a group of input elements. NOT as a group of customizer controls. There's a clear distinction there. Repeaters simply allow you to build a repeatable group of multiple input elements to facilitate things like "social links" settings etc. It does not contain full-featured sub-controls.